# how to scroll till the checked item , when popover is open again?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic-popover

I have a ionic popover , what i need to do is when i select any option from popover that is last in the  list after scroll ,.after the selection the popover gets closed, but when i reopen that popover again it again takes me to the top of the scroll , i want to scroll till the selected item in popover when i open it again ?

here is my html:

```
<script id="templates/ListViewCreator.html" type="text/ng-template">
     <ion-popover-view class="filterpopoverMargins">
      <ion-header-bar  class="">
                <h1 class="title" style="color: black;">Select Views</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>

                <div class="list selectfilterListClass" ng-repeat="item in filterColumn" style="background-color:darkgrey!important;" ng-click="itemCheckedUnCheckedFilterhandler(item)">

                    <label class="item item-radio wrapping-list ">
                        <input type="radio" name="group">

                        <div class="item-content" style="">
                            {{item.label}}
                        </div>
                        <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
                    </label>

                </div>
            </ion-content>
             <ion-footer-bar>
                <button ng-click="defaultSetting()" class="button bar-balanced defaultbtnClass">Default</button>
              </ion-footer-bar>
        </ion-popover-view>
    </script>
```

Kindly help me to get the answer

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ionic/pen/GpCst   , i tried this on the codepen examples available on google it is working their but not working inside my code